# What does Recette say when placing down an item?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

What Japanese sentense/phrase that Recette shouts when place an item in her shop?

I hear the words "nani-kuo-sen-me .... a-do----  ni"?  What is it?  (なに ...?)

This is nagging me for several years.
If possible, please answer it Japanese character.

You can hear it at

.  (10 seconds)

I do not have any affiliate with the clip's channel, if anyone can provide a better link, feel free to comment/edit.

Comment: Hi, I am new here.    Is the downvote for my inability in Japanese or lack of research effort or anything else?

Comment: I can't speak for why the person specifically downvoted you but most downvotes are due to low quality or poorly researched questions. I don't think it's a really bad question but I'm guessing you might find a better answer over on https://japanese.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As for possible reasoning behind the downvote, translating foreign language in a game is getting close to the "off-topic" area.  As far as I can tell, [this meta answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1028/42984) agrees this is on-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She says

"何がいいかな？" which means "I wonder what's good?", while selecting an item from the inventory.

This is followed by "ええい！" which can be translated as "Yeah!" as she puts the heavy item down.